# Fixed div with body scroll

Tags: css, scrollbar, responsive

I have a fixed div 100% height with some content inside:

https://jsfiddle.net/bvr8yp7p/4/

Is it possible to get a scrollbar on body when vertical height is less than the height of the content div? (400px in this example). So that I can scroll vertically blue content top to bottom? (but scroll the page, not just blue content div)

```
<div id="fixed">
  <div id="content"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please be more specific with the example so that we could actually see what the problem is?. Put up some content in your div, so that the problem is properly reproduce

Comment: I have added some content. I would like to scroll that content on body if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps in your other application but in the fiddle case this could help:

```
body {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a div is fixed, it cannot scroll even when the body is being scrolled. If the div must be fixed, then you have to use a script to release it when the body height is lesser than the div height(i.e 400px in your case). See jQuery example below.

```
$(function(){
  var viewHeight = window.innerHeight;
  if(viewHeight < 400){
    $('#fixed').css({position:"relative"});
  }

});
```

Comment: I dont want fixed div to scroll, I want content div to scroll.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get this on time. To scroll only the content, just modify your #content css to look like this 

#content {
    background: blue;
     max-height: 400px;
     overflow:scroll;
}